# Magento extension for single store in multi website

Tags: magento

My client bought an extension named *Extendware Cart Reminder* for a single store. It worked well before creating a another new store for wholesale. He needs that extension for only one store, not for wholesale. But now that extension is not working on both. Is it possible to activate it for only one store? If yes, where should I edit?

Comment: Since this is a commercial extension: have you already contacted their customer support? They should know best what their extensions are able to do and what not.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jürgen Thelen http://www.extendware.com/abandoned-cart-reminder-magento-extension.html  <br/> He bought from here

Answer (score 0):

You could dig into the code and try to customize it a little bit.
Add another configuration option on storeview level in the "General" tab of the extension with the values "enabled/disabled".
Then check at the important places which value is set for the current store view. If it is set to enabled let it execute the original code, if it is set to disabled, do nothing.
As I don't know the code of that extension I can't provide more detailed information. Possibly there is an observer or something where you could check for this configuration value.